# Why is "une culture" frequently followed by plural verbs?

Tags: grammaire, verbes

I don't have a corpus so I'm basing this off the result of Google search: "une culture" is a singular noun, but it seems that "une culture qui ont" is 2 times more frequently seen than "une culture qui a". Why is that?

> Sur tous les plans, vous contestez une civilisation, **une culture qui ont** mis des siècles à se faire.
>
> Il y a des symboles sacrés universels ou propres à **une culture qui font** écho à l'humanité entière

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like just a statistical anomaly.

In the first of your examples, the subject is "une civilisation, une culture" — which is plural because it's a civilisation *and* a culture that took centuries to build up.

In the second of your examples, the subject of "qui font écho" is "des symboles".

Answer (score 6):

In the 1st sentence, the subjects are "civilisation **et** culture". In the 2nd, the subjects are "symboles". In each case, a plural verb is called for.